# "custom archiver out of memory" error when restoring large DB using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, memory, postgresql-9.1, mac-os-x, heroku

I'm trying to a restore a local copy of a 30GB DB (with only one table) dumped using the Heroku wrappers (described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)) using pg_restore.  The Heroku DB is using 9.1.7 and I have had the same result using 9.1.5 and 9.1.7 under OS X 10.8.

Using the command:

```
pg_restore --clean --no-acl --no-owner -d db_name -U username -h localhost -v db.dump
```

I get the following output on the command line ("cleaning" commands omitted) after 20 minutes and seeing the DB size grow to about 30 GB:

```
pg_restore: creating SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating COMMENT SCHEMA public
pg_restore: creating EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: creating COMMENT EXTENSION plpgsql
pg_restore: creating TABLE video_data
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE video_data_id_seq
pg_restore: creating SEQUENCE OWNED BY video_data_id_seq
pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET video_data_id_seq
pg_restore: creating DEFAULT id
pg_restore: restoring data for table "video_data"
pg_restore(11938) malloc: *** mmap(size=18446744071605936128) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
pg_restore: [custom archiver] out of memory
pg_restore: *** aborted because of error
```

Turning up log level to `DEBUG1` reveals the error:

```
...(many of these checkpoints hints)...
LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (15 seconds apart)
HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY video_data, line 463110542: "3599794500:59:01497 797942  2012    23422-08-96 2400892 08.794219   08 0617 2342118769-08 72    115 2046225 1..."
STATEMENT:  COPY video_data (id, video_id, views, favorites, comments, created_at, likes, dislikes) FROM stdin;
```

I have tried increasing `SHMMAX` and `SHMALL` to 2GB, `checkpoint_segments` to 30, as well as upgrading PG to match patchlevels.  A search reveals a small handful of people with this problem several years back, and no resolution.

Any recommendations?

Comment: "extra data after..." - this means malformed line in the dump. is it really your data? can you locate this offending row in the source database?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the record with `id = 463110542`, but all of those numbers after `line 463110542: ` above don't look like my data.  Do you know how to interpret that line number?

Comment: This error says "463110542nd line after `COPY video_data ...` statement inside the dump is broken". You can try to convert the dump to a text file with `pg_restore --clean --no-acl --no-owner -v db.dump -f db.txt`. BTW - did you notice this big number is exactly 16 exabytes? This might be related to a bug in operating system / libs (google for similar bug reports).

Comment: This problem was fixed with another dump, which, coupled with the "extra data" messages, suggests that the original one was corrupt.  The "out of memory" message was a red herring.  Thanks for your help, @filiprem